# How can will I save the attachments from Email using Mapiex in BluePrism?

Tags: blueprism

I am creating an RPA in BluePrism in which bot has to download an attachment(Excel file) from outlook  email. I am using Mapiex

How to save the attachments from E-Mail using Mapiex in BluePrism?

Answer (score 2):

In the action to read email, you have a parameter named 'Attachment Directory':

[image]

All the email attachments will be there after `Get Mail` gets executed. Sometimes though, you may have extra files, usually images from the email, maybe signatures and such. So, you can use the action `Get Files` from the default object `Utility - File Management` and use a filter for .xlsx and .xls files to get the path and names of the files you need:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jerry, Where to download Mapiex LATES VERSION? The one I have do not have the attachment option

Comment: @automaticSoldier on the BluePrism portal. You will have to log in using your email and password. My email domain was registered when my company signed up and I only had to register once.

Comment: Also, somehow that's the version name the people at my place called it, since some people didn't know what was the latest version lol